# Enabling history after using friendly_id for a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I'm trying to add [history](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html#History__Avoiding_404_s_When_Slugs_Change) to an existing production site. I hadn't previously generated the friendly_id migration so after adding it and changing `use: :sluggable` to `use: [:sluggable, :history]` to my model, my ability to `Model.friendly.find...` is gone on any objects that were in the model before I made this change.

What's the best way to address this. Should I just loop through and `.save` on every record in my model during the migration? That's all I've thought of doing so far. Not sure if that would work, but there must be a better way.

#### Update

What I mentioned in my original question is how I went about it. It seems clumsy, but it worked. I'd still love a better answer if one is out there.

```
# Added this to friendly_id migration
class CreateFriendlyIdSlugs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    Model.all.each do |m|
      m.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A more concise way: `Model.all.each(&:save)`

Comment: Also, per https://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History.html, `use: :history` suffices as of 2024 (I’ve tested it, too).

Answer (score 1):

This should work for both mysql and postgresql (which doesn't have INSERT IGNORE)

```
def up
  execute <<-SQL
    INSERT INTO friendly_id_slugs
      (slug, sluggable_id, sluggable_type, created_at)
    SELECT m.slug, m.id, 'Model', NOW()
    FROM models m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN friendly_id_slugs f ON f.sluggable_id = m.id
    WHERE m.slug IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(m.slug) > 0 AND f.id IS NULL
  SQL
end
```

Comment: Maybe this was necessary 10 years ago, but it shouldn’t be anymore. If you run the Friendly ID generator, it will create a migration. See [here](https://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History.html) under ‘Setup’.